# when mapping redux state into props into component it's returning undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

i'm calling a api and getting my data and setting it to redux state successfully but when i'm mapping it to my component it's first returning undefined then it's calling the the api but i'm using redux-thunk for it

this is my header component

```
export class header extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.addUpcomingMovies();
  }

  render() {
    const Movies = this.props.popularMovies.map(movie => (
      <div key={movie.id} className="header-slide-container">
        <div className="header-slide">
          <img
            src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original${movie.poster_path}`}
            alt=""
          />
          {(() => {
            if (!movie.title) {
              return null;
            }
            return <Title movie={movie} />;
          })()}
          {(() => {
            if (!movie.original_title) {
              return null;
            }
            return <OriginalTitle movie={movie} />;
          })()}
          {(() => {
            if (!movie.original_name) {
              return null;
            }
            return <OriginalName movie={movie} />;
          })()}
        </div>
      </div>
    ));
    return (
      <div className="header">
        <div className="header-container">
          <div className="header-slider-wrapper">
            {console.log(this.props.popularMovies)}
            {<Movies />}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  popularMovies: state.upComingMovies.movies
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { addUpcomingMovies }
)(header);
```

this is my upcoming movie reducer

```
const upComingMovie = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_UPCOMING_MOVIES":
      console.log('reducers');

      return {
        ...state,
        movies:action.payload
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export default upComingMovie;

combining reducers 

import upComingMovie from './upcomingMovies';
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
const allReducers = combineReducers({
    upComingMovies:upComingMovie
})
export default allReducers
```

upcoming movie action

```
export const addUpcomingMovies = () => dispatch => {
  console.log("fetching");

  fetch("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/all/week?api_key=25050db00f2ae7ba0e6b1631fc0d272f&language=en-US&page=1")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(movies =>
      dispatch({
        type: "ADD_UPCOMING_MOVIES",
        payload: movies
      })
    );
};
```

this is my store

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware,compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import allReducers from './reducers';
const initialState = {};
const middleware = [thunk];
const store = createStore(allReducers,initialState,compose(applyMiddleware(...middleware), window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()));
export default store;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reducer is not object, your reducer is an array

```
const upComingMovie = (state = [], action) => {}
// ____________________________^
```

But your are using object

```
case "ADD_UPCOMING_MOVIES":

  return { // <--------------- this is an object notation
    ...state,
    movies:action.payload
  }
```

Solution

```
const initialState = {
    movies: []
}
const upComingMovie = (state = initialState , action) => {}
```

Comment: my reducer need's to be an object? where is the use of array inside of it or where do i use it

Comment: Read comments in above code snippet, you defined initial state as array, but returning object

Comment: now it giving me this error this.props.popularMovies.map is not a function

Comment: this.props.popularMovies is empty in start in console then after it's get set

Comment: it's all i was mapping on a object

Comment: @NaveenKashyap you are getting **this error this.props.popularMovies.map** is not a function because data shape returned from api is different, try **this error this.props.popularMovies.results.map** instead

Answer (score 1):

Your `initialState` is wrong, it'd be `{movies: []}`:

```
const initialState = { movies: []};

// ...
const upComingMovie = (state = initialState, action) => {
// ...
```

Also use the same initial state in your store.